# Hyperledger or R3 Corda

Tags: blockchain

Our company is planning to develop a product for trace-ability of a supply chain.  We are looking at considering one of the block chain frameworks Hyper-ledger or R3 Corda.  Could some body tell your views on what to select and why.

Thanks,
Madhu

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use [Emercoin NVS](https://emercoin.com/en/documentation/blockchain-services/emernvs) to maintain trusted history of your supply chain. This is "developer-friendly" public blockchain, and it has open JSON HTTP API for:

- Upload your data into blockchain
- Add ("update") your data
- Retrieve update history

This blockchain is used in [Deloitte DocSensus](https://coinidol.com/deloitte-new-system-on-emercoin-blockchain/) notarization product. 
I can help you to adopt these technologies. Also, will give you testnet EMCs for free, if need.